# how to fix error for installing cutorch with luarocks

Tags: ubuntu, torch

I need help installing cutorch in ubuntu 18.04. I got those result when I ran "luarocks install cutorch" in terminal. I am using CUDA V 9.1.85.

I already tried to run "luarocks install torch" first like other post suggested but I still got the same error when I tried to install cutorch

[ 22%] Building NVCC (Device) object lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCTensorTopK.cu.o
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
CMake Error at THC_generated_THCTensorCopy.cu.o.Release.cmake:279 (message):
  Error generating file
  /tmp/luarocks_cutorch-scm-1-1238/cutorch/build/lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir//./THC_generated_THCTensorCopy.cu.o

lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/build.make:105: recipe for target 'lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCTensorCopy.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCTensorCopy.cu.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
CMake Error at THC_generated_THCTensorIndex.cu.o.Release.cmake:279 (message):
  Error generating file
  /tmp/luarocks_cutorch-scm-1-1238/cutorch/build/lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir//./THC_generated_THCTensorIndex.cu.o

lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/build.make:161: recipe for target 'lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCTensorIndex.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCTensorIndex.cu.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:172: recipe for target 'lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

Error: Build error: Failed building.